# Tomcat неправильно работает с JSP-страницами

Tags: jsp, servlet, tomcat, web.xml, java-ee

Добрый день.

Разбираюсь с сервлетами и JSP. Сделал простенькое приложение:

1. Сервлет *IndexServlet* отображает форму ввода и отсылает данные на 2-й сервлет
2. 2-й сервлет *AddAnswer* принимает данные и через класс-модель *Calculator* получает нужный результат.
3. Сервлет *AddAnswer* вызывает *addResult.jsp* для формирования страницы результата для клиента.

Вот их листинги:

**IndexServlet**

```
package com.exp.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head lang=\"en\">");
        out.println("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
        out.println("<title>Welcome Page!</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=\"/add\">");
        out.println("i = <input type=\"text\" name=\"i\" /> <br />");
        out.println("j = <input type=\"text\" name=\"j\" /> <br />");
        out.println("<input type=\"Submit\" name=\"Submit\" />");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

**AddAnswer**

```
package com.exp.web;

import com.exp.model.Calculator;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AddAnswer extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        int res = calc.add(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("i")), Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("j")));
        request.setAttribute("result", String.valueOf(res));
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("addResult.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**Calculator**

```
package com.exp.model;

public class Calculator {
    public int add(int i, int j) {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

**addResult.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add result</title>
</head>
<body>
  Result = <%= (String)request.getAttribute("result") %>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
         <!--metadata-complete="true"-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.exp.web.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AddAnswer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.exp.web.AddAnswer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AddAnswer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Я использую Intellij Idea 14, Tomcat 8.0.17.

Мой вопрос вот в чем. Я настроил проект так, что все собирается и выкладывается сразу на сервер, все замечательно запускается. Но работает магически для меня:

1. После запуска в браузере открывается страница *http://localhost:8081/SimpleServlet/*. Появляется нужная форма, и можно ввести значения, отправить их кнопкой.
2. После отправки меня перекидывает на страницу *http://localhost:8081/add*, хотя, как я ожидаю, адрес должен быть *http://localhost:8081**/SimpleServlet**/add*. **Почему так?**
3. Если я в проекте в папке web создам просто файлик, например, *example.jsp*, и, запустив сервлет (после деплоя на сервере файлик появляется, где нужно: в корне директории сервлета рядом с папкой *WEB-INF*), перейду по адресу *http://localhost:8081/SimpleServlet/example.jsp* - получу ошибку: **The requested resource is not available.** - **Почему?** Файл на месте, сервер должен просто его отобразить и все. Как я понимаю, не надо прописывать его в web.xml. Методом научного (случайного) тыка я обнаружил, что после деплоя на сервер эта страница доступна либо по адресу *http://localhost:8081/*, либо *http://localhost:8081/example.jsp* (я там несколько страниц создавал, потому в разных случаях по-разному отображалось).

Буду благодарен за "просветление" моих мутных попыток оседлать сервлеты. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

**По пункту 2:**

```
out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=\"/add\">");
```

надо исправить либо на

```
out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=\"add\">");
```

убрать ведущий слеш в action.
либо добавить contextPath к адресу:

```
out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=\"" + request.getContextPath() + "/add\">");
```

то есть, проблема не в томкате, а в пути к сервлету обработчику формы.

**По пункту 3:**

В web.xml прописывать JSP страницы не надо.

Кстати, и объявления сервлетов в `web.xml` не нужны. их можно создать так:

```
@WebServlet(displayName = "AddAnswer", urlPatterns = {"/add"})
public class AddAnswer extends HttpServlet
```

так гораздо проще (Избавляет от ненужной xml конфигурации)

Но проблема не в этом. **Проблема, почему не обрабатывается JSP страница тут:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

то есть, привязав `IndexServlet` к адресу `"/"`, Вы заменили своим `IndexServlet` сервлет по умолчанию (`DefaultServlet`) томката. Поменяйте путь `IndexServlet` на что-то вроде `"/index"` и все заработает